# Error trying to get video author name discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

im trying to take the author video's name on my discord play command and i get this error...

abort(TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)

```js
const vidRequester = message.author;
        const name = message.author.tag
        const songData = ytdl.getInfo(queue[0].url);
            const videoEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setThumbnail(queue[0].thumbnail)
              .setColor('#FA8072')
                .addField('| ▶️ | Melodia actuala:', queue[0].title)
                .setAuthor('Playing | 69%  | soft ', "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/496793735946960916.gif")
              .addField('⏲️ Durata:', queue[0].duration, true)
                .addField('Video Author', songData.videoDetails.author.name, true)
                .setFooter('Facut cu  de @Petre Ispirescu#0060')
                .setTimestamp()
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined` this means when you do `message.author` `message` is `undefined`. Provide the code where `message` is generated.

Comment: Yes my bad, i will make a new comment to put the code, but i don't think its from message

Comment: your `message` object is outside the scope. You need to pass it into the method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
static playSong(queue, message) {
    const classThis = this; // use classThis instead of 'this' because of lexical scope below
    queue[0].voiceChannel
      .join()
      .then(function(connection) {
        const dispatcher = connection
          .play(
            ytdl(queue[0].url, {
              quality: 'highestaudio',
              highWaterMark: 1024 * 1024 * 10
            })
          )
          .on('start', function() {
            message.guild.musicData.songDispatcher = dispatcher;
            dispatcher.setVolume(message.guild.musicData.volume);
        const vidRequester = message.author;
        const name = message.author.tag
        const songData = ytdl.getInfo(queue[0].url);
            const videoEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setThumbnail(queue[0].thumbnail)
              .setColor('#FA8072')
          .addField('| ▶️ | Melodia actuala:', queue[0].title)
          .setAuthor('Playing | 69%  | soft ', "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/496793735946960916.gif")
              .addField('⏲️ Durata:', queue[0].duration, true)
          .addField('Video Author', songData.videoDetails.author.name, true)
          .setFooter('Facut cu  de @Petre Ispirescu#0060')
          .setTimestamp()
```